# How to make the animation loop continuously?

Tags: html, css, animation

**HTML**

```
<div class="about-me-sec-header"><h2><span>A</span><span>b</span><span>o</span><span>u</span><span>t</span>&nbsp;<span>m</span><span>e</span></h2></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(n){
  animation-iteration-count: infinite; //this does not work
}

.about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(1){
  animation: headerAni1 1s linear;
  
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(2){
  animation: headerAni2 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(3){
  animation: headerAni3 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 2s;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(4){
  animation: headerAni4 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 3s;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(5){
  animation: headerAni5 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 4s;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(6){
  animation: headerAni6 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 5s;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(7){
  animation: headerAni7 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 6s;
 }

 @keyframes headerAni1 {
   0%{
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
    border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
   }
   100%{
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
    border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
   }
 }
 @keyframes headerAni2 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}
@keyframes headerAni3 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}
@keyframes headerAni4 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}
@keyframes headerAni5 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}   
@keyframes headerAni6 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}
@keyframes headerAni7 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}



.about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(n){
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(1){
  animation: headerAni1 1s linear;
  
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(2){
  animation: headerAni2 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(3){
  animation: headerAni3 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 2s;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(4){
  animation: headerAni4 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 3s;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(5){
  animation: headerAni5 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 4s;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(6){
  animation: headerAni6 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 5s;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(7){
  animation: headerAni7 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 6s;
 }

 @keyframes headerAni1 {
   0%{
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
    border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
   }
   100%{
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
    border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
   }
 }
 @keyframes headerAni2 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}
@keyframes headerAni3 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}
@keyframes headerAni4 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}
@keyframes headerAni5 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}   
@keyframes headerAni6 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}
@keyframes headerAni7 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}
 <div class="about-me-sec-header"><h2><span>A</span><span>b</span><span>o</span><span>u</span><span>t</span>&nbsp;<span>m</span><span>e</span></h2></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your iteration count gets overridden by your later declarations.

Using the shorthand `animation` property resets the `animation-iteration-count`

After the second line of CSS below, the `iteration-count` gets reset to `1`

```
.someClass {
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation: someAnimation 1s linear;
}
```

Move the section that “does not work” down in the file to just above the key frames:

```css
.about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(1){
  animation: headerAni1 1s linear;
  
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(2){
  animation: headerAni2 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(3){
  animation: headerAni3 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 2s;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(4){
  animation: headerAni4 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 3s;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(5){
  animation: headerAni5 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 4s;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(6){
  animation: headerAni6 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 5s;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(7){
  animation: headerAni7 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 6s;
 }
.about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(n){
  animation-iteration-count: infinite; //this does not work
}

 @keyframes headerAni1 {
   0%{
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
    border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
   }
   100%{
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
    border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
   }
 }
 @keyframes headerAni2 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}
@keyframes headerAni3 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}
@keyframes headerAni4 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}
@keyframes headerAni5 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}   
@keyframes headerAni6 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}
@keyframes headerAni7 {
  0%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Edited with solution

Comment: can make change in with the original code and post it

Comment:  very strange

Comment: Try it with just .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span { animation-iteration-count: infinite; }

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create the full animation using the keyframes and control the time apllying the seconds in all elements using the code at last (above the keyframes config).
I don't know if this result can help you.

```css
.about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(1){
  animation: headerAni1;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(2){
  animation: headerAni2;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(3){
  animation: headerAni3;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(4){
  animation: headerAni4;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(5){
  animation: headerAni5;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(6){
  animation: headerAni6;
 }
 .about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(7){
  animation: headerAni7;
 }

.about-me-sec-header > h2 > span:nth-child(n){
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

 @keyframes headerAni1 {
   0%{
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
    border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
   }
   10%{
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
    border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
   }
   14%{
    border: 0;
   }
 }
 @keyframes headerAni2 {
  10%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  14%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
   28%{
     border: 0;
   }
}
@keyframes headerAni3 {
  14%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  28%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
   42%{
     border: 0;
   }
}
@keyframes headerAni4 {
  28%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  42%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  56%{
     border: 0;
   }
}
@keyframes headerAni5 {
  42%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  56%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  70%{
     border: 0;
   }
}   
@keyframes headerAni6 {
  56%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  70%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  84%{
     border: 0;
   }
}
@keyframes headerAni7 {
  70%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  84%{
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(77, 64, 64);
   border: .1px solid #c651dd ;
  }
  100%{
     border: 0;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="about-me-sec-header"><h2><span>A</span><span>b</span><span>o</span><span>u</span><span>t</span>&nbsp;<span>m</span><span>e</span></h2></div>
```